# Loki : LTSP support

Tags: release-loki

Short question : Is Loki shipped with a support for `ltsp` remote stations ?

Long version : Will the [command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line) `ltsp-build-client`  build a thin client for Loki based on Pantheon ?

Regards

**EDIT 1**

Found a quick way to get a thin client running.
Before launching 'ltsp-build-client' command, you'll need to:

```
cd /usr/share/ltsp/plugins/ltsp-build-client && ln -s Ubuntu elementary
```

Then you can run :

```
ltsp-build-client --debug --dist xenial
```

Using a pxe [tag:boot from a thin client gave me access to a Pantheon session.

But using a 100 Mbts switch is not powerfull enough. Pantheon is really slow and lags on almost every action.

I'll give a try with a gigabite switch.

Comment: Did you try building it as a --fat-client ? I'm interested if this works...

Comment: Please add your solution as answer and mark it as one.